# Android service (location listener) to update activity

Tags: android, android-service

I have an activity that shows a map with markers on it. Also I have a location listener, whose values will update the activity arraylist and cause a redraw of the markers based on the updated arraylist values.

I want this to always run (even if the activity is put in the background). I understand that Activity may get killed so I expect that I need a service for the location lisntener. Now my question is: How can I update the activity arraylist and redraw contents when the service is actually the one obtaining info?

I read something about boundservice so maybe I need that? However  I need the service running even if activity is killed.

OR Do I just create  service and then send a broadcast to activity?

Thank you

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042007/how-can-i-get-return-value-from-android-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you have written at the end of your post you could use a `BroadcastReceiver` for this. That's the way I use it.
In `onCreate(...)` of your `Activity`, register it locally:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(...);
```

in the `onReceive(...)` method of your receiver, update the required data and unregister it in Activity's `onDestroy()` method, again using the `LocalBroadcastManager` object.

Needless to say, you send the broadcast signal from your `Service`'s `onLocationChanged(...)` method, since it is in the same package as your Activity, the LocalBroadcastManager will forward the signal to your Activity.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(...);
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I don't need to deal with the hussle of binding services. My only worry is that a lot of initialization code (like server/db) is done on the activity. I guess, I will have to move all that code to the service then (because activity can get destroyed and lost those variables) correct?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you have to do with the server, but the rule of the thumb is to do all the client/server synchronization independent of the Activity lifecycle. Either use a SyncAdapter class if applicable, or a Service running on a separate thread